# Unable to use yes -command to all questions when removing

Tags: rm

I get a long list of read-only protected files when I run

```
rm -r trunk | yes
```

I am trying to answer yes to all by one command.

**How can you answer yes to all questions?**

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You have it backward, the correct way is:

```
yes | rm -r trunk
```

But the better command would be to have `rm` not ask you in the first place with:

```
rm -rf trunk
```

Comment: This will also remove the directories themselves (rm does not do this by default). However, I'd wager that's usually what you want anyway.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen: That's true with or without the `-f`: the OP include `-r` in the question.